# Intellij Build Works, Maven Build fails

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot, dependencies

at the moment I am building a microservice template project with all technologies I think could be useful, so that people can use it as a base for their projects without going through all the problems I went.

Now the problem: While in Intellij I can run my Spring Boot application but when I am going to use the command "mvn clean install" maven tells me that inside the ms-business the dependencies to other classes are not found. And another problem is when I want to run the *MountainMergerTest* class it can't find the MountainMerger from the same module.

Here you can find the complete project: https://github.com/wscale/mountains

I renamed my project lately maybe that messed it up a bit... but since I tried to reimport it from github the might be broken intellij files should been gone by now... still no change.

I would appreciate every help very much since I don't really get the problem :/

```
mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] mountains
[INFO] ms-commons
[INFO] ms-persistence
[INFO] ms-business
[INFO] ms-ws
[INFO] ms-tests
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mountains 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ mountains ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ mountains ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ mountains ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/pom.xml to /Users/Valdur/.m2/repository/org/wscale/mountains/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mountains-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ms-commons 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ ms-commons ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-commons/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ms-commons ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-commons/src/main/resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-commons/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ ms-commons ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 12 source files to /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-commons/target/classes
[WARNING] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-commons/src/main/java/org/wscale/commons/test/AbstractIT.java: /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-commons/src/main/java/org/wscale/commons/test/AbstractIT.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-commons/src/main/java/org/wscale/commons/test/AbstractIT.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ ms-commons ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-commons/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ms-commons ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-commons/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ ms-commons ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-commons/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ ms-commons ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-commons/target/ms-commons-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ ms-commons ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ ms-commons ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-commons/target/ms-commons-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/Valdur/.m2/repository/org/wscale/ms-commons/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ms-commons-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-commons/pom.xml to /Users/Valdur/.m2/repository/org/wscale/ms-commons/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ms-commons-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ms-persistence 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ ms-persistence ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-persistence/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ms-persistence ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-persistence/src/main/resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-persistence/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ ms-persistence ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-persistence/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ ms-persistence ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-persistence/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ms-persistence ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-persistence/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ ms-persistence ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-persistence/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ ms-persistence ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-persistence/target/ms-persistence-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ ms-persistence ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ ms-persistence ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-persistence/target/ms-persistence-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/Valdur/.m2/repository/org/wscale/ms-persistence/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ms-persistence-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-persistence/pom.xml to /Users/Valdur/.m2/repository/org/wscale/ms-persistence/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ms-persistence-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ms-business 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ ms-business ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ms-business ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ ms-business ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainService.java:[5,35] package org.wscale.mountains.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainService.java:[13,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: interface org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainService
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainService.java:[20,5] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: interface org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainService
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainService.java:[26,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: interface org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainService
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainService.java:[26,5] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: interface org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainService
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainService.java:[32,34] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: interface org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainService
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainService.java:[39,33] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: interface org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainService
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[9,37] package org.wscale.commons.exceptions does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[10,44] package org.wscale.commons.exceptions.errors does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[11,44] package org.wscale.commons.exceptions.errors does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[12,35] package org.wscale.mountains.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[14,41] package org.wscale.mountains.repositories does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[20,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainRepository
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/merger/MountainMerger.java:[3,33] package org.wscale.commons.merger does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/merger/MountainMerger.java:[4,35] package org.wscale.mountains.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/merger/MountainMerger.java:[20,37] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class AbstractMerger
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[26,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[33,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[44,45] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[44,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[56,47] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[67,40] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/merger/MountainMerger.java:[22,42] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.merger.MountainMerger
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/merger/MountainMerger.java:[22,73] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.merger.MountainMerger
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/merger/MountainMerger.java:[22,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.merger.MountainMerger
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[27,20] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[34,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[36,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NotFoundRuntimeException
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[37,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ErrorObject
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[46,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BadRequestRuntimeException
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[47,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ErrorObject
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[73,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[75,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[81,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[83,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NotFoundRuntimeException
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[84,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ErrorObject
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[92,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NotFoundRuntimeException
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[92,52] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ErrorObject
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[105,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BadRequestRuntimeException
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[106,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ErrorObject
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/merger/MountainMerger.java:[24,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MountainEntity
  location: class org.wscale.mountains.merger.MountainMerger
[INFO] 41 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] mountains .......................................... SUCCESS [  0.786 s]
[INFO] ms-commons ......................................... SUCCESS [  3.162 s]
[INFO] ms-persistence ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.995 s]
[INFO] ms-business ........................................ FAILURE [  0.146 s]
[INFO] ms-ws .............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ms-tests ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.542 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-28T16:21:11+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 41M/282M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project ms-business: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainService.java:[5,35] package org.wscale.mountains.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainService.java:[13,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MountainEntity
[ERROR]   location: interface org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainService
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainService.java:[20,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MountainEntity
[ERROR]   location: interface org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainService
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainService.java:[26,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MountainEntity
[ERROR]   location: interface org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainService
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainService.java:[26,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MountainEntity
[ERROR]   location: interface org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainService
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainService.java:[32,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MountainEntity
[ERROR]   location: interface org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainService
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainService.java:[39,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MountainEntity
[ERROR]   location: interface org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainService
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[9,37] package org.wscale.commons.exceptions does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[10,44] package org.wscale.commons.exceptions.errors does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[11,44] package org.wscale.commons.exceptions.errors does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[12,35] package org.wscale.mountains.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[14,41] package org.wscale.mountains.repositories does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[20,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MountainRepository
[ERROR]   location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/merger/MountainMerger.java:[3,33] package org.wscale.commons.merger does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/merger/MountainMerger.java:[4,35] package org.wscale.mountains.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/merger/MountainMerger.java:[20,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class AbstractMerger
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[26,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MountainEntity
[ERROR]   location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[33,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MountainEntity
[ERROR]   location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[44,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MountainEntity
[ERROR]   location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/service/MountainServiceImpl.java:[106,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ErrorObject
[ERROR]   location: class org.wscale.mountains.service.MountainServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/Valdur/Documents/Development/Projects/mountains/ms-business/src/main/java/org/wscale/mountains/merger/MountainMerger.java:[24,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MountainEntity
[ERROR]   location: class org.wscale.mountains.merger.MountainMerger
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :ms-business
```

Comment: The usage of `${global.version}` will not work like that. Please see the [docs how to use that in Maven 3.5.0](http://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html). The question who should inject (autowire) the MountainMerge into your unit test? I don't see any usage of springboot test runner (If i correctly remember) etc. Furthermore can you put a full logout of the maven build into the post...to see the real error messages...

Comment: Thanks so far, I changed the ${global.version} and changed the Autowire into a new. The error is still the same.

Comment: Please post the log output as I already requested...Checked the springboot docs how to run unit tests ?

Comment: I was figuring out how to add the log in the proper format now its there ;) The test did run before I came into that maven problem (I tried to fix it with @Autowire but now is the test again like it was originally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging into this...the usage of spring-boot-maven-plugin in the parent is not intentional for a multimodule build. This will inherit that to all sub modules which means each sub module will be repackaged by `spring-boot-maven-plugin:repackage` and create a bootable jar but which can't be consumed be the other modules (classpath) which results into much of the above errors. If you comment that out into the root parent first you will go further during compilation but fail with other issues.

You have put a AbstractIT into ms-commons which you should extract to a separate module like `ms-tests` into the `src/main/java` area which means it will be packaged into a jar and can simply being reused in other modules. But by using this test module you should use the scope `test`for this dependency.

About the reason why it works in IDE but not with Maven. In an IDE the modules will be resolved by the IDE and not by Maven which means if you have the modules imported into your IDE everything is found it is not based on backed jar files. But on command line it's more strict only based on the dependencies and of course based on the created JAR files.

If you take a look into the produces jar files (via spring-boot-maven-plugin:repackage):

```
Archive:  ms-commons/target/ms-commons-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    testing: META-INF/                OK
    testing: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF     OK
    testing: BOOT-INF/                OK
    testing: BOOT-INF/classes/        OK
    testing: BOOT-INF/classes/org/    OK
    testing: BOOT-INF/classes/org/wscale/   OK
    testing: BOOT-INF/classes/org/wscale/commons/   OK
    testing: BOOT-INF/classes/org/wscale/commons/dto/   OK
    testing: BOOT-INF/classes/org/wscale/commons/exceptions/   OK
    testing: BOOT-INF/classes/org/wscale/commons/exceptions/errors/   OK
    testing: BOOT-INF/classes/org/wscale/commons/hateoas/   OK
    testing: BOOT-INF/classes/org/wscale/commons/merger/   OK
    testing: BOOT-INF/classes/org/wscale/commons/dto/ItemCollection.class   OK
    testing: BOOT-INF/classes/org/wscale/commons/exceptions/AbstractRuntimeException.class   OK
    testing: BOOT-INF/classes/org/wscale/commons/exceptions/ErrorObject.class   OK
```

They contain the correct classes but the location inside the jar is not the jar default which means it can't be consumed by classpath.

Comment: Thanks you so much khmarbaise, that really helped me a lot. I was able to fix all the problems I described above :) Changes are in github. Its far from final yet the project but if you have seen some other things I could improve feel free to criticize the project ;)